# Javascript Algorithm to find the best combination(least number of items) of lengths less than a given value

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, combinations, permutation

How to find the best combination of n values which gives the least amount of sum ( n1+n2+n3+n4+n5)

```
maxDiff = D
requiredLength = L

lengthArray = [l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6]

1st constraint,
diff = L - (n1*l1 + n2*l2 + n3*l3 + n4*l4 + n5*l5)

2nd constraint,
0 >= diff <= D
```

Here, `l` are different length values of sheets ( 1000mm, 1100mm, ..., 2000mm etc)
`L` is the maximum length required (entered by an user).
i want to calculate the best combination of `n` values(>=0) which basically returns the least number of sheets.

if there is a diff, this can be the gap between sheets. (it can also be 0)

Answer (score 0):

You can find solution with dynamic programming

Make array `A` of size `L+1` containing item counters (initially 0) and the last item added.

For every item length `li` walk through array from index range `k`: from `A[i] to A[l]`

If adding item `li` to `A[k-li]` makes count in the cell `A[k]` better (lower), replace current value in `A[k]`. Pseudocode:

```
if (A[k-l[i]].count + 1 < A[k].count) 
   {
     A[k].count = A[k-l[i]].count + 1; 
     A[k].item =  l[i];
   }
```

Finally check if `A[L]` contains item set. If now, walk down to get closest result.

To retrieve items, go down by `A[k].item` steps